# How to select the outermost CellGroup that contains given cell?

Tags: performance-tuning, programming, notebooks, cells

Suppose we have a Notebook with a deeply nested structure (this is a simplified example, the Notebook can be huge):

```
nb = CreateDocument[{ExpressionCell[0, "Section"], ExpressionCell[1, "Section"], 
    ExpressionCell[2, "Subsection"], ExpressionCell[3, "Subsubsection"], 
    ExpressionCell[4, "Input"], CellGroup[{ExpressionCell[4, "Output"]}]}];
```

And a cell located inside one of the nested groups:

```
cellObj = Last@Cells[nb];
```

If we know how deeply our cell is nested, it is easy to select the outermost `CellGroup`:

```
SelectionMove[cellObj, All, CellGroup, 4]
```

[image: screenshot]

But what if we don't know the nesting level? How can we select the outermost `CellGroup` in this case?

Currently I know only an extremely inefficient iterative approach:

```
nesting = Module[{n = 1, scPrev, scCurr},
 SelectionMove[cellObj, All, Cell];
 scPrev = SelectedCells[nb];
 While[SelectionMove[cellObj, All, CellGroup, n];
  (scCurr = SelectedCells[nb]) =!= scPrev,
  scPrev = scCurr; ++n];
 n - 1]

SelectionMove[cellObj, All, CellGroup, nesting]
```

> ```
> 4
> ```

Is there a more efficient way?

P.S. The fact that `SelectionMove[cellObj, All, CellGroup, 5]` doesn't return `$Failed` in this case I consider as a bug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple answer is to specify a large enough value for the fourth argument of `SelectionMove`, which is very unlikely to be exceeded in real life. The timings linearly depend on it, but are not large:

```
ListPlot[Table[First[AbsoluteTiming@SelectionMove[cellObj, All, CellGroup, n]], {n, 15}], 
 PlotRange -> All]
```

> [image: output]

In real life, it is extremely unlikely to find a Notebook with `CellGroup` nesting larger than 15. Hence we can simply take this value as a "practical infinity", which ensures that the outermost `CellGroup` will be selected.